# How to delete numpy nan from a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of strings

```
x = ['A', 'B', nan, 'D']
```

and want to remove the nan.

I tried:

```
x = x[~numpy.isnan(x)]
```

But that only works if it contains numbers. How do we solve this for strings in Python 3+?

Comment: @Kasramvd Can you explain what you mean by "numpy nan"?

Comment: @JoshLee The `non` object from numpy module which the OP is using. I change it to numpy so that the future askers can find the question easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a numpy array you can simply check the item is not the string `nan`, but if you have a list you can check the identity with `is` and `np.nan` since it's a singleton object.

```
In [25]: x = np.array(['A', 'B', np.nan, 'D'])

In [26]: x
Out[26]: 
array(['A', 'B', 'nan', 'D'], 
      dtype='<U3')

In [27]: x[x != 'nan']
Out[27]: 
array(['A', 'B', 'D'], 
      dtype='<U3')


In [28]: x = ['A', 'B', np.nan, 'D']

In [30]: [i for i in x if i is not np.nan]
Out[30]: ['A', 'B', 'D']
```

Or as a functional approach in case you have a python list:

```
In [34]: from operator import is_not

In [35]: from functools import partial

In [37]: f = partial(is_not, np.nan)

In [38]: x = ['A', 'B', np.nan, 'D']

In [39]: list(filter(f, x))
Out[39]: ['A', 'B', 'D']
```

Comment: aggregate things like: `[i for i in x if not i in ['nan', np.nan]]`, +1 otherwise

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Yeah, that's a good idea if you don't know that kind of a data structure you're dealing with.

Comment: NaN is not a singleton.

Comment: @JoshLee Why? I think as far as you can't create different instances from a particular object it would be refer as singleton. Is there anything special about `np.nan`?

Comment: `np.nan` is just some floating point constant. You wouldn't compare `is math.pi` either, for the same reason.

Comment: @JoshLee Well, IMHO, it doesn't make any difference, almost everything in python is object even the code, and once something is object it can be singleton or a regular object (AFAIK) like integers between -5 to 256 or other single tones in python that get cached in memory instead of having multiple instances with different ids.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `math.isnan` and a good-old list comprehension.

Something like this would do the trick:

```
import math
x = [y for y in x if not math.isnan(y)]
```

Comment: Did you try `math.isnan('A')`?  Test on the OP's `x`?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to avoid `np.nan` with strings, use `None` instead; but if you do have `nan` you could do this:

```
import numpy as np

[i for i in x if i is not np.nan]
# ['A', 'B', 'D']
```

Comment: NaN is not a singleton.

Comment: @JoshLee I didn't say it's a singleton. I just said it might be better to use None instead of `nan` in string cases, which will be converted to a string `nan` but `None` stays as `None`.

Comment: You're comparing with `is`. This will fail.

Comment: @JoshLee I didn't get what you mean. It works for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
[s for s in x if str(s) != 'nan']
```

Or, convert everything to `str` at the beginning:

```
[s for s in map(str, x) if s != 'nan']
```

Both approaches yield `['A', 'B', 'D']`.