# Deleting nan from a string array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list, numpy

I have a following array:

```
data=array([['beef', 'bread', 'cane_molasses', nan, nan, nan],
       ['brassica', 'butter', 'cardamom']])
```

How can I delete the nan's to get:

```
 array([['beef', 'bread', 'cane_molasses'],
       ['brassica', 'butter', 'cardamom']])
```

I have tried the method given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980345/how-to-delete-numpy-nan-from-a-list-of-strings-in-python) but this does not work as in my case my array is of higher dimension and is not a simple vector.

Comment: Your array is 1d, shape (2,).  But it contains lists.  You could apply the linked answer to each of those lists.  For most purposes your array is a list - a list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object` dtype arrays do not support vectorised operations. But you can do a round trip converting first to `list` and then back to an array. Here we use the fact [`np.nan != np.nan` by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values):

```
data = np.array([['beef', 'bread', 'cane_molasses', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                 ['brassica', 'butter', 'cardamom']])

res = np.array([[i for i in row if i == i] for row in data.tolist()])

array([['beef', 'bread', 'cane_molasses'],
       ['brassica', 'butter', 'cardamom']], 
      dtype='<U13')
```

Note the resultant array will be of string types (here with max length of 13). If you want an `object` dtype array, which can hold arbitrary objects, you need to specify `dtype=object`:

```
res = np.array([[i for i in row if i == i] for row in data.tolist()], dtype=object)

array([['beef', 'bread', 'cane_molasses'],
       ['brassica', 'butter', 'cardamom']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution but a very dangerous piece of code to include in any data processing pipeline as it will break silently if the not-a-number specification changes.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen, `np.nan != np.nan` is fundamental to `NaN` as a concept, e.g. the docs for `np.isnan` have "NumPy uses the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point for Arithmetic (IEEE 754)." The rationale is built into IEEE 754 ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/9209546)). It may not be seemly, but neither is it the worst assumption.

Comment: Sorry, I was maybe too imprecise. I am not worried about the not-a-number standard changing in numpy, I am worried about OP changing the way he or she imports data such that for example `nan` becomes `'nan'`, etc.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen, That's a fair point, thanks for raising it. My solution does indeed assume the user can rely on null values being `np.nan`.